# vbs regex: match the text between ONLY the FIRST 2 underscores

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

I'm doing some filename scraping with VBS, if the file name was called

```
hello_world_2012_is_not the end of the world.pdf
```

then the regex should match the word "world" and **nothing else**.

I tried this:

```
[_][^_]+(?=_)
```

but it gets everything that is between two underscores. How do I only select the first occurrence?

Comment: Do you want to know if the file name contains the word "world"?

Comment: Sorry... saw the answer at the title

Comment: Good point. No I want to extract it so it could be anything...not as easy as looking for "world" I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the following regex:

```
/^[^_]*_([^_]*)_/
```

Explanation:

```
^        # Anchor the search to the start of the string
[^_]*    # Match any number of non-underscores, don't capture them
_        # Match the first underscore
([^_]*)  # Match any number of non-underscores, do capture them
_        # Match the second underscore.
```

Then the first capturing group (`$1`) will contain `world`, and the regex won't match anywhere else in the string.

Comment: Excellent! No need to use string manipulators to extract underscores. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The regex itself should look something like this:

```
_([^_]*)_
```

The string is captured into group 1.

Alternatively, use string functions to locate the first 2 underscores and then extract what's between them.